# задание значения автосвойству объекта класса с заданным именем C#

Tags: c#

Имею следующий код:

```
private bool isIObjectModelable(object ourCurrentObject, string sobject, object parameter1){
  if (CurrentObject is IObjectModel) {
         TypeInfo t = typeof(SqlA).GetTypeInfo();
         IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> pList = t.DeclaredProperties;
         var newCorrentObject = CurrentObject as IObjectModel;
         newCorrentObject.SomeAction += (index) =>
         {
             **((SqlA)index).Property1 = parameter1;**
             return AlterActionType.Property;
         };
    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;
}
```

Класс SqlA содержит много автосвойств с открытым сеттером, задача состоит в том чтобы присвооить нужному  свойству значение parameter1, название свойства идет во втором параметре string sobject.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Берем тип
var type = ourCurrentObject.GetType();
// Находим в нем нужное свойство
var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(sobject);
// Устанавливаем это свойство у конкретного экземпляра в конкретное значение
propertyInfo.SetValue(ourCurrentObject, parameter1);
```